# Is it possible to fetch user account balance in smart contract?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, anchor-lang

Is it possible to fetch account balance or token balance in the smart contract itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read and write from the accounts which are included in the transaction. This is how you get the token balance and the SOL balance (in lamports):

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let bal = ctx.accounts.token_account.amount;
    let sol_bal = ctx.accounts.admin.lamports();
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub staking_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
}
```

You cannot fetch the balance of an account which is not included in the accounts array in the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Hey yes you can always access the lamports of an account that was passed into the transaction like so :

```
let lamports = ctx.accounts.player.lamports();
```

or mutable

```
**ctx
                .accounts
                .player
                .to_account_info()
                .try_borrow_mut_lamports()?
```

You can even change them if you have signer rights for the account that you are subtracting from:

```
        **ctx
            .accounts
            .chest_vault
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= CHEST_REWARD;
        **ctx
            .accounts
            .player
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += CHEST_REWARD;
```